# Conditional Execution - Multiple Commands

Tags: bash

Using conditional execution I know that I can do this:

```
[ -e "$filename" ] && echo "found" || echo "not found"
```

I want to execute several commands in the true||false sections.

I know I can do

```
if [ -e "$filename" ]; then
    command1;
    command2;
else
    command3;
    command4;
fi;
```

but is there a way to do something like this on a single line?

```
[ -e "$filename" ] && command1 command2 || command3 command4
```

Comment: Your first example doesn’t do _quite_ what you think it does. If `echo "found"` would fail (unlikely, but imagine it’s some other command) then `echo "not found"` will be executed even if `[ -e "$filename" ]` succeeded.

Comment: I take your point. I'll ensure I pay attention to the possibility of the second command returning an unexpected value and this screwing-up the logic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command Groups!

```
[[ test $variable ]] && { success one; success two; } || { failure one; failure two; }
```

This is also useful if you want to avoid running the failure condition like a real if/else:

```
[[ test $variable ]] && { false; true; } || echo will not run
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was after.